# How to decode a base64 PDF without encryption in TCL?

Tags: pdf, base64, tcl

Using Tcl in a integration suite called Cloverleaf, the programming language used is TCL.
The command I'm using for it is correct `set dcpdf [::base64 -mode decode $pdf]` the packege is called earlier in the code, the problem is that after the code base64 is decoded and we try to open the file it requires a password, there is no passwork inhereit to the file, is there a arg to the decode comand that stops this issue?

Comment: Can you say for sure that no password was used to protect the file? Because I don't think the package can do anything more than encoding and decoding, see the [documentation](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-19/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/base64/base64.html)

Comment: Which `::base64` command are  you using? The one in tcllib (version 1.20) does not have the interface you give and binary encoding / decoding with the core Tcl commands uses the `binary` command.

Comment: The base64 encoding (supported natively in 8.6; see `binary encode` and `binary decode`) has no password protection concept at all. It just says how to map full binary data to some ASCII characters for carrying around in places that don't like full binary data. Encryption is a different level of concern.